# What is the best software for creating OpenGL ES models and textures?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

What is best software for creating models , textures etc... for iphone development.

From simplest to more complex programs.

First thing that comes to my mind is blender , but I'm  curious what everybody else is using and their opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Cheetah 3d , it looks decent and it exports directly to header files.

I will definitely try blender , but it seems overwhelming and i am not sure do i need to loose to much time on getting to know how to work in blender. 
On other hand i was trying out cheetah 3d and i figured out most of the staff in couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

Blender is a very good issue for your needs.

It's a very complete solution. Just take your time to learn it step by step. You'll get some great tutorials on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed! I found a tutorial about 3D programming mentioning Blender as a free tool. It was SO daunting to use at first, and I still haven't even figured out most of what it can do. However, I can now build and export the needed geometries for my applications.

Tips:

- Use a 3 button mouse (RMB:Selects a vertice, edge or face; MMB Rotates the view camera)
- 'A' selects or deselects all
- 'X' deletes anything selected (prompts you first)
- 'B' Bounding Box Selection Mode
- 'E' Extrude selected things

For creating textures, I use Adobe's Illustrator, Photoshop and Fireworks, and then import the image into Blender. There is also a texture paint mode in Blender as well.